# segmentation fault in pthread programming

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a program to read a file with lines like: `number operator number` and want to handle these lines with 4 separate threads using pthreads and show the result of each line with the format of:

Line number Result

My file has 2 operators: plus and minus.  When I run code only with `subReadThread` (and `subExec`) or only with `plusReadThread` (and `plusExec`) it works correctly and give me the correct result but when I want to run the threads together I get segmentation fault error and the execution process does not continue.

Here is the code (also at http://pastebin.com/2fDSDucm):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5
#define TRUE 1
int numberOfLines ;
int sumCounter, subCounter, mulCounter, divCounter ;
int sumFileEnd, subFileEnd, mulFileEnd, divFileEnd ;
pthread_t *tid ;

clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

sem_t sumfull, sumEmpty ;
sem_t subfull, subEmpty ;
//sem_t mulfull, mulEmpty ;
//sem_t divfull, divEmpty ;
//sem_t outfull, outEmpty ;

char sumBuff [5][25] ;
char subBuff [5][25] ;
//char mulBuff [] ;
//char divBuff [] ;
//char outBuff [] ;

pthread_mutex_t sumMutex ;
pthread_mutex_t subMutex ;

void initData(){
        pthread_mutex_init(&sumMutex, NULL)      ;
        sem_init(&sumfull, 0, 0) ;
        sem_init(&sumEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) ;
        sem_init(&subfull, 0, 0) ;
        sem_init(&subEmpty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) ;

        sumCounter = subCounter = mulCounter = divCounter = 0 ;
        sumFileEnd = subFileEnd = mulFileEnd = divFileEnd = 0 ;
}

void *plusReadThread(){
        printf("Enter to the plusReadThread\n");
        FILE *sumfp = fopen("sample.txt","r");
        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        char *isSum ;
        int lineNumber = 1 ;
        if (lineNumber == 1){
                read = getline(&line, &len, sumfp) ;
                lineNumber ++ ;
        }
        while (!feof(sumfp)){
                printf("Enter to the while of plusReadThread\n");
                read = getline(&line, &len, sumfp) ;
                isSum = strchr(line, '+') ;
                if (isSum != NULL){
                        printf("Down on sumEmpty\n");
                        sem_wait(&sumEmpty);
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&sumMutex) ;
                        printf("Lock the mutex in plusReadThread\n");
                        if(sumCounter < BUFFER_SIZE){
                                printf("Counter was < 5 in plusReadThread\n");
                                char temp[20] ;
                                sprintf(temp, "%d", lineNumber);
                                strcat(temp, ".");
                                strcat (temp, line);
                                printf("lineNumber is %d line content is %s", lineNumber, line );
                                strcpy(sumBuff[sumCounter], temp);
                                printf("Copied the line in to the sumBuff\n");
                                printf("sumCounter = %d sumBuff[%d] = %s",sumCounter, sumCounter, sumBuff[sumCounter] );
                                sumCounter ++;
                                printf("sumCounter changed to %d\n", sumCounter);
                        }
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&sumMutex);
                        printf("Unlock the mutex in plusReadThread\n");
                        sem_post(&sumfull);
                        printf("Signal on sumfull\n");
                }
                lineNumber ++;
        }
        if (feof(sumfp))
                sumFileEnd = 1;
        fclose(sumfp);
}
void *plusExec(){
        printf("Enter to the plusExec\n");
        char *search = "+" ;
        char *temp1;
        char *temp2;
        int operand1 ;
        int operand2 ;
        int result ;
        while (!sumFileEnd || sumCounter!=0){
                printf("Enter to the plusExec while\n");
                printf("Here sumCounter is %d \n", sumCounter);
                sem_wait(&sumfull);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&sumMutex);
                printf("Lock the mutex in plusExec\n");
                temp1 = strtok(sumBuff[sumCounter-1], search) ;
                operand2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, search));
                temp2 = strtok(temp1, ".") ;
                operand1 = atoi(strtok(NULL, ".")) ;
                result = operand1 + operand2 ;
                printf("%d %d\n", atoi(temp2) ,result);
                sumCounter --;
                sem_post(&sumEmpty);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&sumMutex);
                printf("Unlock the mutex in plusReadThread\n");
        }
}

void *subReadThread(){
        printf("Enter to the subReadThread\n");
        FILE *subfp = fopen("sample.txt","r");
        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        char *isSub ;
        int lineNumber = 1 ;
        if (lineNumber == 1){
                read = getline(&line, &len, subfp) ;
                lineNumber ++ ;
        }
        while (!feof(subfp)){
                printf("Enter to the while of subReadThread\n");
                read = getline(&line, &len, subfp) ;
                isSub = strchr(line, '-') ;
                if (isSub != NULL){
                        printf("Down on subEmpty\n");
                        sem_wait(&subEmpty);
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&subMutex) ;
                        printf("Lock the mutex in subReadThread\n");
                        if(subCounter < BUFFER_SIZE){
                                printf("Counter was < 5 in subReadThread\n");
                                char temp[20] ;
                                sprintf(temp, "%d", lineNumber);
                                strcat(temp, ".");
                                strcat (temp, line);
                                printf("lineNumber is %d line content is %s", lineNumber, line );
                                strcpy(subBuff[subCounter], temp);
                                printf("Copied the line in to the subBuff\n");
                                printf("subCounter = %d subBuff[%d] = %s",subCounter, subCounter, subBuff[subCounter] );
                                subCounter ++;
                                printf("subCounter changed to %d\n", subCounter);
                        }
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&subMutex);
                        printf("Unlock the mutex in subReadThread\n");
                        sem_post(&subfull);
                        printf("Signal on subfull\n");
                }
                lineNumber ++;
        }
        if (feof(subfp))
                subFileEnd = 1;
        fclose(subfp);
}
void *subExec(){
        printf("Enter to the subExec\n");
        char *search = "-" ;
        char *temp1;
        char *temp2;
        int operand1 ;
        int operand2 ;
        int result ;
        while (!subFileEnd || subCounter!=0){
                printf("Enter to the subExec while\n");
                printf("Here subCounter is %d \n", subCounter);
                sem_wait(&subfull);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&subMutex);
                printf("Lock the mutex in subExec\n");
                temp1 = strtok(subBuff[subCounter-1], search) ;
                operand2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, search));
                temp2 = strtok(temp1, ".") ;
                operand1 = atoi(strtok(NULL, ".")) ;
                result = operand1 - operand2 ;
                printf("%d %d\n", atoi(temp2) ,result);
                subCounter --;
                sem_post(&subEmpty);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&subMutex);
                printf("Unlock the mutex in subReadThread\n");
        }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv []){
        begin = clock();
        FILE *fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r") ;
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &numberOfLines) ;
        fclose(fp) ;

        initData() ;
        tid = (pthread_t*)malloc(4*sizeof(pthread_t)) ;
        pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,plusReadThread,NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,plusExec,NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid[2],NULL,subReadThread,NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid[3],NULL,subExec,NULL);

        pthread_join(tid[0] , NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[1] , NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[2] , NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[3] , NULL);

        end = clock();
        time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("%F\n", time_spent);
        exit(0);
}
```

When I run code only with subReadThread(and subExec) or only with sumReadThread(and sumExec), it works correctly and gives me the correct result. But when I want to run the threads together(as in above link), I get a segmentation fault error and the execution process does not continue.
Here is the output of one of my runs (at http://pastebin.com/nBqfiDcW):

```
6 1222
5 -2369
3 -2355
2 -1593
12 3306
11 4688
9 4549
7 4834
4 1827
10 -2571
23 7537
21 3789
19 1751
15 2803
13 2673
8 1304
34 588
33 3367
29 6922
26 4204
25 5212
20 364
18 -1890
17 37
37 1658
16 -1867
36 4541
14 -2184
48 7613
47 3093
44 3349
40 2516
30 -1163
28 -530
38 1016
27 1403
24 -1102
22 989
56 5370
54 4465
53 4918
35 -565
51 4918
32 1169
31 1781
43 941
42 525
41 1359
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Function signatures should be `void* foo(void*)` for functions passed to `pthread_create`

Comment: I corrected them but still it has segmentation fault

Comment: your code is too long. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or run it in a debugger and post the stack trace.

Comment: this is the result of debugging @mescalinum : http://pastebin.com/vVfYa84h

Comment: that does not containa stack trace. ensure you compile with the `-g` option, and in gdb issue the `bt` command.

Comment: excuse me it was my mistake that is what you want i think @mescalinum: http://pastebin.com/vuH9Py8s

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7834517 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7830f60 in atoi () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000401258 in subExec () at cm.c:138
#3  0x00007ffff7bc4182 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff78f147d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

it was in subExec() line 138 of cm.c that you called [`atoi()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) and it segfaulted.

Doublecheck what you pass to [`atoi()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html).

In particular, you pass the result of [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), so doublecheck that it is doing the correct thing.

Also, you can get better understanding of what is causing this issue if you step your program, inspect variables and so on.

Look for some introductory tutorial on using gdb, such as [this](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa09/cse141/tutorial_gcc_gdb.html).

Comment: i have checked it.i print the thing which is sending to atoi and it was a correct thing.also i use it In the SumExec Function above of this Function and it is worked correctly

Comment: And when i seprated sum and sub threads i seprated files, they worked correctly whitout any SegFault.